# each record have its own table with header

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to have the table setup for each record instead of all the records in the database. I can do it with asp.net but can't figure how to do it with php. I just need a sample not the work done for me or a book or link that shows how to do it.

```html
<?php
require_once("../db_connect.php");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$sql = "SELECT id, lanId, name, department, manager, request, request_description, request_comments, status, comments, compUser, compDt FROM requests WHERE status='received'";
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



echo"Received Requests";
echo "<br><br>";
echo("<table  bgcolor=F2F2F2 width=1000 border='2'>");

echo("<tr><th>Id</th><th>LanID</th><th>Name</th><th>Department Location</th><th>Manager</th><th>request</th><th>request_description</th><th>request_comments</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th><th>Completed User</th><th>Completed Date</th><th>Update</th></tr>");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

echo("<tr>");

echo  "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>"
."<td>" .  $row['lanId'] . "</td> "
. "<td>".  $row['name'] . "</td>"
. "<td>". $row['department'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['manager'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_description'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['status'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compUser'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compDt'] ."</td>"
."<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>";



echo '</tr>';

}
echo("</table>");

?>


<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body background="../images/background.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Just put the table tags inside the the while loop

```
echo("<table  bgcolor=F2F2F2 width=1000 border='2'>");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
echo("<tr><th>Id</th><th>LanID</th><th>Name</th><th>Department Location</th><th>Manager</th>      <th>request</th><th>request_description</th><th>request_comments</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th> <th>Completed User</th><th>Completed Date</th><th>Update</th></tr>");
echo("<tr>");

echo  "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>"
."<td>" .  $row['lanId'] . "</td> "
. "<td>".  $row['name'] . "</td>"
. "<td>". $row['department'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['manager'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_description'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['status'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compUser'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compDt'] ."</td>"
."<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>";



echo '</tr>';
echo("</table>");
}
```

Comment: that was so simple. Also is there a way to get the table rows and header go to another line like split them up

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: I wanted to split up the information so that it goes in 2 rows. first row have <th>LanID</th><th>Name</th><th>Department Location</th><th>Manager</th><th>request_description</th>  the second row have <th>request</th><th>request_comments</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th> <th>Completed User</th><th>Completed Date</th><th>Update</th>

Comment: with the data in the table underneath each corresponding header

Comment: Glad you figured it out.